# In Perl, how do I get an arbitrary value from a hash?

Tags: perl, hash

Consider a populated hash:

```
%hash = ( ... );
```

I want to retrieve a value from the hash; any value will do.

I'd like to avoid

```
$arbitrary_value = (values %hash)[0];
```

since I don't really want to create an array of keys, just to get the first one.

Is there a way to do this without generating a list of values?

NB: It doesn't need to be random. Any value will do.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Assume that I don't know any of the keys.

Comment: Updated to confirm that I don't know any keys

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

my %h = qw(a b c d e f);

my (undef, $value) = each %h;
keys %h; # reset iterator;

print "$value\n";
```

As pointed out in the comments, [In particular, calling keys() in void context resets the iterator with no other overhead](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html). [This behavior has been there at least since 2003](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/2f65b2f0bd345fd58390bf7bbb7e2f9c96839f76) when the information was added to the documentation for [keys](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) and [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html).

Comment: `scalar` is overkill. Your explicitly making it do more work by evaluating it in scalar context instead of void context. Although just a tiny bit more (creating a scalar with the number of keys, returning it, then freeing it)

Answer (score 3):

Just as an exercise, and using the `%h` variable provided by Sinan, the following works for me:

```
my (undef, $val) = %h;
print $val, "\n";
```

And of course, the following also works:

```
print((%h)[1], "\n");
```

Fun fact: it appears that Perl uses the same approach than the one used for `each`, but without the iterator reset catch.